# Generalising the data binding operation

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can I create a method to do work with these five sections? I'm doing binding operations so many times.  Do you have an idea on how to make this code prettier?

- `ddlModelValue` -> ASP.NET `DropDownList`

```
var dtModel = Session[SystemConstant.ModelSessionKey] as DataTable;
ddlModelValue.DataSource = dtModel;
ddlModelValue.DataTextField = "Name";
ddlModelValue.DataValueField = "Name";
ddlModelValue.DataBind();

var dtGroup = Session[SystemConstant.GroupSessionKey] as DataTable;
ddlGroupValue.DataSource = dtGroup;
ddlGroupValue.DataTextField = "Name";
ddlGroupValue.DataValueField = "Name";
ddlGroupValue.DataBind();

var dtFit = Session[SystemConstant.FitSessionKey] as DataTable;
ddlFitValue.DataSource = dtFit;
ddlFitValue.DataTextField = "Name";
ddlFitValue.DataValueField = "Name";
ddlFitValue.DataBind();

var dtShellType = Session[SystemConstant.ShellTypeSessionKey] as DataTable;
ddlShellTypeValue.DataSource = dtShellType;
ddlShellTypeValue.DataTextField = "Name";
ddlShellTypeValue.DataValueField = "Name";
ddlShellTypeValue.DataBind();

var dtDataTypeCode = Session[SystemConstant.DataTypeCodeSessionKey] as DataTable;
ddlDataTypeCodeValue.DataSource = dtDataTypeCode;
ddlDataTypeCodeValue.DataTextField = "Name";
ddlDataTypeCodeValue.DataValueField = "Name";
ddlDataTypeCodeValue.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be a start:

```
Sub bindTableToControl(table as DataTable, _
                       control, _
                       Optional textField As String = "Name", _
                       Optional valueField As String = "Name")

 control.DataSource = table;
 control.DataTextField = textField;
 control.DataValueField = valueField;
 control.DataBind();

End Sub

bindTableToControl( ddlModelValue , Session[SystemConstant.ModelSessionKey] );
bindTableToControl( ddlGroupValue, Session[SystemConstant.GroupSessionKey] );
bindTableToControl( ddlFitValue, Session[SystemConstant.FitSessionKey] );
bindTableToControl( ddlShellTypeValue, Session[SystemConstant.ShellTypeSessionKey] );
bindTableToControl( ddlDataTypeCodeValue, Session[SystemConstant.DataTypeCodeSessionKey] );
```

Basically I removed most of the repetition. I also removed all the Hungarian prefixes in the Sub.

As a side note, I wonder why SystemConstant is part of the Session, that does not seem memory efficient?